# Unable to query AWS cross-account datashare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-sharing

I'm using cross-account data sharing on Redshift and when I try to get data from the Consumer cluster, for example:

```
select * from ds.schema_name.table_name;
```

I got an error:
ERROR: Internal Service Error.
And that's it...

The Producer cluster was deployed with a manual snapshot from other cluster.